# lightning-quick-action-panel remove scroll using css LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system, design-attributes, css3

I am using lightning-quick-action-panel in the html and the component loads on a button click and it contains a data table.
There are 2 scrollbars present and I want to get rid of one .When I inspected the element I changed the overflow-y to "hidden". But how to include this in css.

```
<lightning-quick-action-panel header="Edit">
```

[image: base image]

[image: changes]

[image]

```
    .slds-modal__content{  
    overflow-y: hidden !important;  
  } 
  .runtime_platform_actionsQuickActionWrapper .quick-actions-panel {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
.runtime_platform_actionsQuickActionWrapper {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
.quick-actions-panel {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```